# How to make functions that change the state via useState hook reusable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reusability

Let’s say I have the following code for changing the input values and it updates the state of the component:

```
const handleInputChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let type = e.target.type;

    // some other code

    setInput(nextState);
  };
```

However, since I have different components using this same function, I’d like to make it an exportable utility function. But then it has the “setInput” function call coming from `useState` hook.

Should I just pass the `setInput` as a parameter to every `handleInputChange()` call like:

`onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, setInput)}`

Or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: wouldn't it scream `jsx-no-bind` with that?

Comment: @tanmay Can elaborate?

Comment: [jsx-no-bind](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) eslint rule would trigger with the approach you've mentioned. Although, I don't see a better way myself. Here for that itself :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a custom hook, you can just call other hooks in there. So you could just retrieve `setInput` within the hook instead of passing it in there:

```
const useCustomHook = (initialValue) => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState(initialValue);

  // ...

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let type = e.target.type;

    // some other code

    setInput(nextState);
  };

  return handleInputChange;
}
```

This `input` would be bound to the state of the component, which is calling `useCustomHook`.

EDIT:

Combining @Shota's answer with this one, you could create a component using the `useState` hook to handle the state internally aswell:

```
const CustomInput(initialState) => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    // ...
    setInput(nextState);
  };

  return (<input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} />);
}
```

To use `input` in the outside world just return it from the hook:

```
useCustomHook = () => {
  // ...
  return {
    handleInputChange,
    input
  }
}
```

Comment: Not so clear on this.. what if I need the input's state in other parts of the component that's using the `useCustomHook`? E.g. when input is changed via `handleInputChange()` the new input's state will be reflected in another sibling component.

Comment: You can just add it to the response object of that hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a brand new reusable component with the on change function prop.

```
import React from 'react';

const CommonInput = ({handleChange}) => {

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    let type = e.target.type;

    // some other code

    setInput(nextState);
    handleChange(nextState);
  };

  return (<input type="text" onChange={handleInputChange} />);
}

export default CommonInput;
```

And we can reuse it anywhere we want:

```
import React from 'react';

const Parent = (props) => (
  <CommonInput handleChange={nextStateData => {}}/>
  );

export default Parent;
```

Generally, I would prefer creating a new component with some functionality inside than reusing just functions.